# About Qt Shadow Build for Ubuntu or Win

Tags: windows, qt, ubuntu

When I set a new Qt project, Qt provides to set a new folder containing all compiled items (object files and so on), avoiding to "mix" with my source and header files.
Suppose I have some graphic elements stored in a separated folder: linking them to some item inside my application, path will be different if I'm working in Qt Designator from that when the project is compiled.
So, I'm wondering if is it possible to set Qt in such a way I put external references (as images for labels) in one folder only instead of two (one used when I design and one when the project is already compiled).

Answer (score 1):

You need to embed your images into the application binary using [Qt Resources](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html).